# Как сделать, чтобы сайт открывался в Android приложении, а не в браузере?

Tags: android, html, css, xml

Идея такова: при запуске приложения - запускается сайт, но не в браузере, а в самом приложении. Как мобильная версия. Такое реализовать возможно, а то в инете я не нашёл информации об этом? Соответственно чтобы все ссылки на этом сайте также открывались в приложении, а не в браузере.

Опыт в разработке Android-приложений имею, не большой, но всё же есть. Как и в разработке сайтов, поэтому не полный ноль) Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Там есть в элементах браузер

Comment: и называется он `WebView`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте компонент `WebView`, как уже правильно заметили в коммантариях.
Однако производительность веб приложения ниже, чем нативного. Если приложение целиком состоит из `WebView` - такое приложение не нужно.

Comment: _"Если приложение целиком состоит из WebView - такое приложение не нужно."_ Нужно. Во-первых, оно может работать оффлайн. Во-вторых, там есть доступ а нативному api.

Comment: @Qwertiy, не нужно. Это уже пройденный этап, сейчас пора изучать и начинать делать PWA. https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/

Comment: я думаю от случая к случаю. Где-то выгодно, где-то нет. Есть сайты, пользоваться которыми через мобильный браузер не удобно из-за маленьких кнопочек. Приложения нет. А тут сделаешь приложение, создашь удобные кнопки для управления с телефона и всё. Остальное всё делает сервер сайта. Выгодно? Думаю да.